# How to get admin access to multiple namespaces on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, rbac

I have an application that has two parts: one deployer and the application runtime environment. The deployer needs to have access to different namespaces to be able to launch, edit and delete the application deployments, svc, configmaps, etc.

I first launch the deployer via a helm chart and then the deployer exposes some APIs to manage the application (launch, edit, delete).

My question is how to write the `ClusterRole` for my deployer that can only have access to a set of pre-created namespaces without giving it full cluster access (deployer should not be able to create, edit or delete namespaces). OR I have to create one `Role` for each of those namespaces and add them to the Helm chart of the deployer before installing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `ClusterRole` that will describe what the role can do. Then create a `RoleBinding` in each namespace you want the role user to have the priviliges. Here is a nice example from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-example):

> A RoleBinding can also reference a ClusterRole to grant the permissions defined in that ClusterRole to resources inside the RoleBinding's namespace. This kind of reference lets you define a set of common roles across your cluster, then reuse them within multiple namespaces.
>
> For instance, even though the following RoleBinding refers to a ClusterRole, "dave" (the subject, case sensitive) will only be able to read Secrets in the "development" namespace, because the RoleBinding's namespace (in its metadata) is "development".

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
# This role binding allows "dave" to read secrets in the "development" namespace.
# You need to already have a ClusterRole named "secret-reader".
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-secrets
  #
  # The namespace of the RoleBinding determines where the permissions are granted.
  # This only grants permissions within the "development" namespace.
  namespace: development
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: dave # Name is case sensitive
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: secret-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```